# Suggest terms to describe language proficiency level in your CV

Tags: programming-languages, computer-vision

What's the best way to describe your level of skill in particular technologies (languages, platforms, OS, ...) when polishing your CV ?
Assume we are talking about the *short CV* of the kind where you don't spell out every project and system you have worked on in the past, but still want the reader to get a general appreciation of how well you master each topic.

Can you suggest a set of labels which is unambiguous but sufficiently general to be understood across the industry?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/36840/listing-my-programming-experience-on-my-resume

Answer (score 8):

As a hiring manager, I like it when people state how many years they used a language and when they last used it.  Also, when describing projects you worked on, be sure to list what languages you used on each.  It's frustrating to see someone with C++ (or any language) on their resume but not listed next to any projects.

Answer (score 5):

Number of years of experience is usually what HR people look for since it is more verifiable and ostensibly objective than words like "expert" et. al.

Comment: Which is enormously sad.  Also leads to idiotic crap like "requires 3 years of experience in sql server 2008"

Answer (score 5):

Labels are so ambiguous as to be meaningless. Instead, describe working projects you have actually done in each language. E.g. "Wrote 30 T/SQL stored procedures for SQL Server 2005 for updating an ORM, and 10 triggers for integrity validation". "Wrote back-end LINQ to SQL ORM in C# for an ASP.Net 3.5 web service".

Answer (score 3):

In past years, I have added qualitative terms to my resume but only in a structured way.  So, for example, I've used things like "Expertise in C#, SQL and Delphi" and then "Familiar with Lisp, PHP,..." etc.  The idea isn't necessarily to rank yourself against others - the years of experience and the types of projects worked on will do that - it is to show where you are deepest in a relative sense among all of the technologies that you have learned.

The other benefit, of course, is that you are showing a sense of proportion and perspective about your own talents.  If you said you were "expert" in more than three technologies, I'd be pretty skeptical.  If you indicated expertise in 2-3 and familiarity with many more, it would raise much less of a red flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a scale system, e.g. 1-5 with 1 being the least and 5 being the most.  Be quantitative not qualitative as that can bring in various definitions that aren't likely to be what you'd prefer.